# How to underline a text in a question or an answer?

Tags: support

I read the [Markdown help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) and the [basic HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed) but I can not find anything about the capability to **underline** a text.
Is it possible ? and how?

I'd like to know that in order to illustrate [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/354036/32413) about Unicode character
to write :
[image]
without having to take a picture

Comment: Take a look at [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @mitch thank you, there is lots of features described in this link, I will reuse it, but no underline capability ;(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no markdown here to allow underlining and the CSS method isn't possible either because it's requires restricted tags or attributes.

You could use unicode. It has so much space for characters in 16-bits that they decided to do the whole alphabet with underlining:

> T̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲i̲s̲ ̲j̲u̲s̲t̲ ̲a̲n̲ ̲e̲x̲a̲m̲p̲l̲e̲,̲ ̲i̲t̲ ̲i̲s̲n̲'̲t̲ ̲p̲e̲r̲f̲e̲c̲t̲.̲
>
> ͟a͟n͟o͟t͟h͟e͟r͟
>   ͟e͟x͟a͟m͟p͟l͟e

Of course these mappings aren't simple to remember (I think there is a Compose-key layout for them) so there are tools like [Unicode Underliner](http://thejh.net/misc/unicode-underline) that do the bulk of the work for you.

Or you can use XML Unicode `&#x332;`and `&#863;` before each letter. The second is longer better for "m", although the support is somewhat dodgy on some browsers (or systems that don't have a proper install of the Ubuntu fonts).

I would beg you to use it only when you really, really *need* it though. The last thing I'd like to see here is an all-out formatting war.

Comment: perfect answer, and your link is perfect for what I needed! and ok I'll avoid underline as much as possible

Comment: One reason to avoid it worth mentioning is that underlined text on the web is usually a clickable link.

Comment: That Unicode underlined text looks like squares for me in Windows (fine in Ubuntu, though). It shouldn't be assumed that every font will support this.