# Help with formatting text in question and answer

Tags: support, text-formatting

We can easily well format text in question/answer like Bold, Italic, Hyperlink, Block-quote, code, Image, List, Heading and Horizontal rule.

Now, I want to know various tags like `<kbd>`, etc. which **can be used** in formatting of body of question/answer.

Hence Give me such list and use of tages or from where can I learn about them?

Comment: Take a look at [Editing Help](http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @Mitch : How underlines to text?

Comment: @Seth : Can I underlines text as "<u>" tag is not allowed?

Comment: NO, you can't use <u> tag.  Here is a list of allowed [tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @Mitch : Then is there any method to underline text? or it is prohibited?

Comment: At this point there is no way to underline text.  You can modify your question, asking to have the feature added, and use the `feature request` tag.

Comment: See [this Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117016/why-can-we-format-text-with-bold-and-italic-but-sideline-the-underline) question for reasoning on why underlining is not permitted.

Comment: @minerz029 : I saw that question, and There is very helpful answer.Ok.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7424/how-to-underline-a-text-in-a-question-or-an-answer